# howto run entire class on second thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am digging into multithreading, found some good tutorials but I have some remaining questions.

I figured how to run one function async, (see this [tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246911-c#-multi-threading-in-a-gui-environment/)) there are four examples to archieve that.

But in the application I am developping I want to run an entire class in a seperate thread. I'm looking for something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace multithread_test
{
    class Program
    {
        Program()
        { }
        RunInBackground RIB;

        void StartBackgroundWorker()
        {
            // how do  I get RIB to run in the background?
            RIB = new RunInBackground();
        }

        //somefunction to listen to the CallEventToUpdateGUI
    }


    //This class should run in a different thread than class Program
    class RunInBackground
    {
        void RunInBackground()
        { }

        void Function1()
        {
            //somefunction
        }

        void Function2()
        {
            // somefunction
        }

        void Function3()
        {
            Function1();
        }

        void CallEventToUpdateGUI()
        {
            //call a event to update gui
        }

    }
```

Comment: Classes don't run in threads. Methods do. Methods run on the same thread as their callers (usually). If `RIB` was "running" on another thread, and then you called `RIB.Function1()` from within `Program`, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: I'd expect this function to be ran on the other thread, but probably it is stupid to think like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread is about **execution** of the code and not about definiton of it. You can not do this. 
What you can do is only **run** the code on ohter thread.

You also can *instantiate* a class on another thread, but it's by the way is not a definition of it.

Comment: ok, so if i call a function in a seperate thread, and from that function i call other functions, those functions are all ran on the same seperate thread?

Comment: That does make threading some easyer... but at the same time more complex, I'm going to study some more about this subject, try some things. Thanks !